# What are the odds that there is no solution on a given Set board?

Tags: probability, cards

I was playing a [game of Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(game)) with a group.  We had the usual twelve cards out and all agreed that there was no set.  We then increased the number of cards to fifteen and were still unable to find a set.  (Unfortunately I no longer have a picture of the board in question, so it's impossible to verify.)

Is this even possible?  Were we all just really, really tired?  What are the odds of this occurring?

Comment: I know for a fact I've had it happen to me, with 18 cards.  I don't know the exact odds, but I do know it's possible.

Answer (score 3):

[Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28game%29#Basic_combinatorics_of_Set) the chance of no set being present in 15 cards when playing is $88:1$.  This assumes that the first twelve cards have no set.  It also says you can find twenty cards with no set.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the probabilities, but I thought I'd address the question "Is this even possible?".

Here's a favourite paper of mine, [The Card Game Set](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/staff/D.Maclagan/papers/set.pdf). In it they give a collection of twenty cards with no set, which is apparently the maximum (i.e. 21 cards must contain a set somewhere):

[image: Twenty and no set]

So yes, it's perfectly possible to have no set within 15 or even 18 cards!

Comment: That set board is so infuriating. There are way too many almost-sets.